# Angular Typescript union types function calling

Tags: angular, typescript, union-types

So I want to pass an `Array<number|string>` to a function that accepts `Array<number|string>` and returns that what you input, so it could be `Array<number>` or `Array<string>`.

But the method overloading seems to not work properly. What am I missing to get it working?

---

user.model.ts

```
export interface User {
  text: Array<string | number>;
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserService {
  public getText(text: Array<string>): Array<string>;
  public getText(text: Array<number>): Array<number>;
  public getText(text: Array<string | number>): Array<string | number> {
    return text;
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const user: User = {
      text: ["string"]
    };

    this.userService.getText(user.text);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(text: string[]): string[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(text: number[]): number[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
      Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2769)
```

Repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-resonance-ilfvm?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `Array<string | number>` is an array of strings or numbers (e.g. [1, 'a', 2]). `Array<string> | Array<number>` is either an array of strings or an array of numbers.

Comment: If you genuinely do want getText to return an array of strings or an array of numbers (`Array<string> | Array<number>`) then that's possible, but what will be the behavior if the input array contains both strings and numbers?

Comment: Now I've taken the answer that @Tommos provided. That returns either `Array<string> | Array<number>` or `Array<string | number>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
export class UserService {
  public getText(text: Array<string>): Array<string>;
  public getText(text: Array<number>): Array<number>;
  public getText(text: Array<string | number>): Array<string | number>;
  public getText(text: Array<string | number>): Array<string | number> {
    return text;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the overloads are doing anything here are they? If you take out the first three lines that start `public getText` the method behaves the same I think?

Comment: @Rich N The first three lines are defenetly doing something! If you input text of type `Array<string>` you can ONLY get `Array<string>` back. Same for `Array<number>`. But if you remove the first three lines then you could always receive an array containing strings AND numbers